# Regex on Firebase Security API?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Is there any way that I could do regex on Firebase security rules like .match() in JavaScript? Because I can't seem to find anything about it in Firebase documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase now supports regular expressions in it's security rules using the `String.matches()` function. Docs are here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/api/string/matches.html

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there is not.  There are only the string functions listed [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/string/index.html).  We'll likely add regular expression support sometime in the future, but there are some [performance issues with regular expressions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/regex-performance.html) that we want to be careful to avoid, so it's probably not coming super soon.

Comment: .contains(), .endsWith(), and .beginsWith() seem like they could address a good cross-section of regex needs, though!

Comment: What about validating a slug name against the title property of the master id? For example say the `title` of my article is `"Fun with FireBase!"` whos master id is `-J1jafDD45_a2112`. You would need regex server-side to ensure the slug URL generated client side is the same. `slugs`-->`fun-with-firebase`